# Google calendar API v3: recurrence begins on the wrong day

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, google-calendar-api

I am developing a web application, where you can create and edit events that are in the google calendar.

My problem is that when I create an event and add a recurrence, the first event comes out on a wrong date, but others recurrence depart on the correct date.

Example:

I do an event on August 15 (Saturday) which will have a recurrence: Monday, Wednesday and Friday until 30 September.

Below is the recurrence rule I used:

```
RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR;UNTIL=20150930T040000Z
```

The problem is that it creates an event Saturday August 15(incorrectly), and then begins the following Monday recurrence correctly.

The correct behavior is to not make the event on 15 August.

Anyone have pointers or know how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrence only defines when the event will repeat. For the event to start on the correct date, you need to create it on the correct date.
For example:
Your first day of work is on a Saturday. After that, you will work every Monday, Wednesday, and Friday. In this case, the calendar behavior is correct.

Comment: Thank you gave me an idea and I was able to do it :D